# JSON Display just one data using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have this json, and i want to display just "cat_news" in my html5 using javascript,

```
[
{
    "id_news": "3",
    "cat_news": "Category Three",
    "title": "News Content next",
    "content": "testingg\nThis is some content\nwith long post\n",
    "media": "7e3e9-komodo.jpg",
    "message": "Broadcast message news 3"
}
{
    "id_news": "4",
    "cat_news": "Category Three",
    "title": "News Content next",
    "content": "testingg\nThis is some content\nwith long post\n",
    "media": "7e3e9-komodo.jpg",
    "message": "Broadcast message news 3"
}
]
```

but when i use my script :

```
$(data).each(function() {
var title = "<h3 class='title-a'>"+ this.cat_news + "</h3>";
$('#title').append(title);
});
```

it display repeated (more than one result).
Can you help me to display it just one result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function runs twice, i.e. for element 0 and 1 of your array. This produces two `h3` tags in your `#title`. If this is not the intended behaviour, you can access the array objects directly using something like this: `data[index].cat_news`, where `index` is the array's index, starting from 0 (in your case 0, 1).

If you want the `cat_news` of the last element, just use `data[data.length - 1].cat_news`.

Comment: Verry good answer, i use data[0].cat_news and it display just one result.

Answer (score 1):

Try like that:

```
$(data).each(function(index) {
var title = "<h3 class='title-a'>"+ data[index].cat_news + "</h3>";
$('#title').append(title);
});
```

Also, you are missing a "," between the objects in the data array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display just one element don't use a loop, just get the element from json data or pass an id or a filter to the function to return just one

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wkrx1o5/)

```
$(data).each(function() {
    var title = "<h3 class='title-a'>"+ this.cat_news + "</h3>";
    $('#title').html(title);
});
```

Instead of append use html

I would however suggest that you maybe change your JSON so that you don't have the cat_news in both objects